# How can I upload and then download a file through flask?

Tags: python, flask

I prepared a script in which user can upload a file as an input file (text.dat) and then after importing it into a function (compute), another file as an output (server.log) can be downloaded by user.

But the script does not work properly - it requests for the input file but can not be downloaded at the end.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect, send_file, 
from compute import compute

app = Flask(__name__)




@app.route("/")
def fileFrontPage():
    return render_template('fileform.html')

@app.route("/handleUpload", methods=['GET','POST'])
def handleFileUpload():
    if 'photo' in request.files:
        photo = request.files['photo']
        if photo.filename != '':            
            photo.save(os.path.join('/home/Documents/web', photo.filename))

    return redirect(url_for('fileFrontPage'))

@app.route('/download', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])   
def tes():  
  with open("/home/Documents/web/download/server.log", "w") as fd, open('/home/Documents/web/text.dat', 'r') as out:
    path = "server.log"
    for i in out:
        s = compute(float(i))
        fd.write("{} \n".format(s))
  return send_file('/home/Documents/web/download/server.log',as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='server.log')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

My html file as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple file upload using Python Flask</title>
    </head>
    <body>        


        <form action="/handleUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Choose the file: <input type="file" name="photo"/><BR>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be calling `tes` anywhere.

Comment: To expand. I don't see anything that actually tries to retrieve the function tes... tes seems like it would return the file.

Comment: When I exclude the first section (html) downloading works while uploading does not.

Comment: Well, yes, now you have two functions on the same URL. That can't possibly work; why are you doing it?

Comment: So. how can I send the output file?

Comment: I  changed the route name, but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the route of `tes()` to something that doesn't conflict with `fileFrontPage()`, e.g. `@app.route('/download')`

Comment: Can I put both in a same route? I mean the second and third.

Comment: You could, but why? it's cleaner being separated. You would need to add `'GET'` into `methods` of `handleFileUpload()`, and then add `if request.method=='GET':` (and one for `POST`) to determine which code to execute within the function.

Comment: I changed the route of tes() but still the server can not send me the output (server.log), while the uploading works well and gets and saves the file on the server.